# How to use Bouncycastle's CMac

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle, cmac, siv-authenticated-encryption

I'm trying to use BouncyCastle's CMac implementation but apparently I'm doing it wrong. At least the following unit test (based on RFC 5297 test vectors) fails:

```java
@Test
public void testCMacOfZeros() {
    byte[] key = {(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xfc, //
            (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xf8, //
            (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0xf4, //
            (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0xf0, //
            (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xf3, //
            (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0xf7, //
            (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xfb, //
            (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xff};

    byte[] zeros = new byte[16];

    byte[] result = new byte[16];

    CipherParameters params = new KeyParameter(key);
    BlockCipher aes = new AESEngine();
    CMac mac = new CMac(aes);
    mac.init(params);
    mac.update(zeros, 0, 16);
    mac.doFinal(result, 0);

    byte[] expected = {(byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0xaf, //
            (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x04, //
            (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x28, //
            (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x3a};

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, result);
}
```

I assume, that the CMac implementation itself is well tested, so I must miss something.

Comment: Kind of obvious maybe, but you can test the CMAC implementation using the CMAC test vectors instead of the SIV specific ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake:

> SIV-AES uses AES in CMAC mode (S2V) and in counter mode (CTR).  SIV-
>      AES takes either a 256-, 384-, or 512-bit key (which is broken up
>      into two equal-sized keys, one for S2V and the other for CTR)

I should have used only the first 16 bytes from the given key.

As expected, BouncyCastle works just fine.