# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: CmacAES for provider BC

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Class to calculate CMAC which is used as PRF in KDF for SCP03 PseudoRandom CardChallenge generation
 */
public class Cmac {

    /**
     * Tested CMAC against official TestVectors ({@link 'http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/SP_800-38B.pdf'})
     * CMAC used as PRF in KDF
     */

    public static byte[] calc(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] data) throws ApduGeneratorException {
        try {
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length, "AES");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("CmacAES", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            mac.init(key);

            byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(data);

            return hash;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApduGeneratorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This code is causing such exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: CmacAES for provider BC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:97)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:222)
    at com.quantag.globalplatform.sm.Cmac.calc(Cmac.java:23)
    at app.executors.LoadAppletExecutor$1.call(LoadAppletExecutor.java:102)
    at app.executors.LoadAppletExecutor$1.call(LoadAppletExecutor.java:1)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$492(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$493(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have already installed [JCE unlimited 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and added: `security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`
according to [Provider Installation docs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation). 
 But I am still getting this exception. What have I missed?

I am using a such version of BC: **bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar**.

Comment: please mention bouncycastle version

Comment: Or you can just instantiate it directly, assuming it's there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516804/how-to-use-bouncycastles-cmac

Comment: If you mean to run this test. It is failed because of assert, but there are no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have replaced:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("CmacAES", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

with this new code:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("AESCMAC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

The exception gone and all is working perfectly.

Comment: Now replace `Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("AESCMAC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)` with `Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("AESCMAC")` and you'll be adhering to best practices.